# Align statement breaks on rhs with equal sign

Tags: indentation, align

Is there a way to have rhs statement breaks align with the equal sign on the lhs line?
e.g.

```
some_value = a * b + c
    / some_other_value * x;
```

becoming

```
some_value = a * b + c
             / some_other_value * x;
```

I can only figure out how to have it a consistent offset, which means that different lhs variable names won't have the rhs equation lines align correctly.

Comment: which mode is this and which command are you using to align? perhaps there's an answer on the emacs wiki: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AlignCommands

Comment: cmode and I've checked those, they give me column alignment for a series of assignment statements on the equals sign but not to align the line-broken rhs under the lhs equal sign.  I'd like to be able to get it so I can just hit tab and let auto-indent sort it out, this feels like something that c-offset variables should deal with but I can't find anything in the documentation for this in particular.

Comment: Do you see the same behavior when starting with `emacs -Q`?

Comment: Yes, running with emacs -Q yields the same behavior where the broken lines get one extra c-offset indent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(defun c-lineup-statement-cont-rhs (langelem)
  "Line up multi-line statements on the rhs in front of the assignment operator"
  (save-excursion
    (let* ((relpos (cdr langelem))
           (curcol (progn (goto-char relpos)
                          (current-column)))
      (re-search-forward "=" (c-point 'eol) 'move)
      (goto-char (match-beginning 0))
      (+ 2 (- (current-column) curcol)))))
```

Where the +2 at the end will put it in front of the equal sign, rather than directly below it.

Full disclosure, I'm not entirely sure how this works.  I basically just used the stream operator lineup function example from 
http://kirste.userpage.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/cc-mode/cc-mode_6.html